# Can I install another desktop environment in elementary OS?

Tags: desktop, gnome

I would like to install the Gnome desktop and LXDE on my elementary to gain some more fps on my games also to make it look different and don't get bored of the same.

is it possible and if it's, is the same as Ubuntu or should i run the other desktop environment via terminal?

Comment: I'd recommend against this. In my experience, all you end up with is a mess of a system.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably possible to remove Pantheon/Granite and install GNOME on elementary OS, but it's also a bad idea. :) Installing GNOME would likely result in an unstable OS. In addition, apps that are designed for Pantheon/Granite may break in GNOME.

I'd recommend installing a version of Ubuntu that is configured to work with your desktop environment of choice. For LXDE, there's [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me/). For GNOME, there's [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/). You can install another flavor of Ubuntu alongside elementary, run it on a virtual machine, or boot it from a live CD if you just want to do a test drive.

For way more details, see [this question about installing KDE](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4879/test-kde-on-elementary).

Comment: hi,i dont want to uninstall Pantheon, i just want to have the option to choose between desktops.

Comment: This Ask Ubuntu thread has more information on installing desktop environments and switching between them: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments That said, following these instructions may break stuff. Gnome and Pantheon require different versions of the same libraries, so installing Gnome may make Pantheon unusuable. If you do this, I'd recommend trying it in a virtual machine first before touching the environment that you use every day. Dual booting or installing in a VM is a safer way to go.