# How can I install Cinnamon on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, desktop, user-interface

I'm looking to install the Cinnamon DE (which is default under Linux Mint) on my machine running Loki. How can I do this?

Comment: Is that an experimental project? Any reason not to use Linux Mint? In any case it's up to you and I respect whichever considerations you should have taken. I recommend to read the answer of @cipricus which I subscribe 100%. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4903/6398

Comment: No real reason not to use Linux Mint, I just want to try it out on an OS I've got installed before committing to a whole other OS install (if needed; if Cinnamon runs smoothly under EOS I'll just stick with EOS).

Comment: I would think it would be a bad idea to have 2 de on the one installation, you are going to run into lots of problems.